# LINQ / C# Remove all items from a list that are in multiple other lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I have the following setup:

- 1 list containing about 500 products.
- 1 list of assortments each containing a list of products (that are inside the assortment) and some other properties.

My model looks like this (smiplified):

```
public Model() {
   public List<Products> {get; set;}
   public List<Assortment> {get; set;}
}
```

and the assortment looks like this (simplified)

```
public Assortment() {
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<Product> Products {get; set;
}
```

#### I would like to display **all products that are NOT in any assortment**.

I tried something like this:

```
Model.Products.Except(x => Model.Assortments.Where(y => y.Products.Contains(x)).Select(z => z.Products).ToList()
```

But the compiler tells me

> "Lambdaexpression" cannot be converted into type
> "IEnumerable" because it's no delegate type

(translated from german into english)

I also tried something with RemoveAll or Where but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using SelectMany you can get all products in any assortment

```
Model.Assortments.SelectMany(a => a.Products)
```

so the products which are not in any assortment are:

```
Model.Products.Except(Model.Assortments.SelectMany(a => a.Products))
```

As @GuruStron noted in a comment, this assumes that the products in the assortments can be identified with the products the Products collection either because they are the same object or by a suitable `Equals` override.

Comment: I would add a note that to work correctly this possibly needs `Product` class to have overloaded `Equals` method.

Comment: This works! Thanks so much, didn't know it was that easy